# opening android browser with parameter passing and return to application

Tags: android, android-studio

i have a button in my android app. i want to open browser when user click on button, close browser and return to current activity with parameter after user finish the process on browset How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you aren't really able to pass variables FROM the web unless you have it use a Javascript callback, then close. At most you can get that you closed the browser.

The application should resume if it was last on the application stack. But you really should just have a webview with your own custom controls to close the screen. In which case you are not getting it from the webview but the manager for your webview.. Javascript is the only way to get data From a webpage.

IE 
[How to return value from webView.evaluateJavascript callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322904/how-to-return-value-from-webview-evaluatejavascript-callback)